# PDF autofill using javascript nested if statement error

Tags: javascript, acrobat, nested-if, conditional-execution

I have a pdf with two input text boxes. 1.) Item Code and 2.) Item

I am trying to populate "Item" based on "item code" but the nested statements are giving me data for the first else if condition below for all cases. For example, I should get "20% 100 ML" for code 5009113 and "25% 50ML" for code 5009111, and so on. Instead, I am getting "20% 100ML" for any and all values in item code. Please help me with this :)

```
var v = this.getField("Item Code").valueAsString; 
var RXC = Number(v); 
if (v=="") event.value = ""; 
else if (RXC=5009113) event.value = "20% 100ML"; 
else if (RXC=5009111) event.value = "25% 50ML";
else if (RXC=5009112) event.value = "25% 100ML";
else if (RXC=5009099) event.value = "5% 250ML";
else if (RXC=5009110) event.value = "5% 500ML";
```

Comment: You might consider using a switch statement instead of all those if statements.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions in your `else if` statements contain expressions such as the following:

```
RXC=5009113
```

This is an assignment expression: you are assigning the value `5009113` to the variable `RXC`. This is considered to be a "truthy" statement and therefore it evaluates to `true` and therefore no more `else if` statements are considered.

Instead of this you should use the comparison operator `===`. Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript) regarding the difference between `==` and `===` - and why it is better to use `===` here.

I personally prefer to use white space characters to separate out the parts of an expression:

```
else if (RXC === 5009113)
```

It makes it easier (for me) to see what is going on - and easier to spot where I may have used `=` instead of `===`.

But I would recommend re-working the entire section of code to use "if/else" with braces, as follows:

```js
if (v === "") {
  event.value = "";
} else if (RXC === 5009113) {
  event.value = "20% 100ML"; 
} else if (RXC === 5009111) { 
  event.value = "25% 50ML";
} ...
```

And probably even better would be to use a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), as mentioned in the comments. This is going to be less cluttered than several if/else statements: easier to read, debug, and maintain.